# If и JSON в С#?

Tags: c#, json

Как сделать проверку если не существует элемента в json ?
Есть json от стим веб апи(http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview?appid=730&market_hash_name=...), который я получаю в своем проекте c#, обычно в json есть median_price, но иногда его нет(Например здесь есть - http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview?appid=730&market_hash_name=Negev%20%7C%20Army%20Sheen%20%28Minimal%20Wear%29&format=json , а здесь нет http://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview?appid=730&market_hash_name=StatTrak™%20M4A4%20%7C%20Howl%20%28Field-Tested%29&format=json). Я бы хотел сделать проверку на его наличие.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: исправил, теперь думаю вопрос развернутый )

Comment: Простейший вариант вызвать метод `Contains()` у переменной содержащей ваш json текст.

Comment: Чем вы парсите JSON?

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json

Answer (score 4):

Используйте JSON.Net, мой вам совет...

Берем JSON, который может быть и создаем на его основе класс:

```
public class Root
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("lowest_price")]
    public string LowestPrice { get; set; }
    public int Volume { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("median_price")]
    public string MedianPrice { get; set; }
}
```

Обратите внимание на то, что название каждой переменной должно быть такое же, как и в `JSON`, но не всегда это красиво в коде и для этого мы указываем `JsonProperty` с именем, которое находится в `JSON` - это позволит нам назвать переменную как угодно.

Имея класс под наш `JSON` - мы можем сделать десериализацию:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(StringData);
```

`StringData` - ответ от сервера, в виде `String`.

Ну и дальше спокойно работайте с данными. К примеру, если прочесть `JSON` с одним значением `Success` и вывести все данные на экран:

```
Console.WriteLine(json.Success);
Console.WriteLine(json.LowestPrice);
Console.WriteLine(json.Volume);
Console.WriteLine(json.MedianPrice);
```

То в ответ мы получим:

> False
>
> 0

То есть говоря другими словами, при десериализации `JSON` - вы получите только те данные, которые есть в файле, остальное будет иметь `NULL`. И тут вы можете делать нужные вам проверки:

```
if (json.LowestPrice != null) //как пример...
```

В общем, в вашем случае не обязательно отслеживать есть ли на сервере это значение, или его нету. Главное правильно десериализовать!